# How can I search for a specific item with attributes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to test if a player has the following item:

```
minecraft:bow 1 0 {display:{Name:Bow I},ench:[{id:48,lvl:1}]}
```

*A bow with a name of "Bow 1" and has a Power I enchantment.*

I know this command works with normal items:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:bow"}]}
```

I don't know how to add the attributes. Is it possible to search for a specific item name?  For example, test to see if I have the item "Bow I" in my inventory?

Comment: Half the answer is here: http://hypixel.net/threads/testfor-snowball-with-custom-name.71759/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command for spawning chest with a CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/command-for-spawning-chest-with-a-canplaceon-tag)

Comment: @pppery The linked question, under no circumstances, could be considered a proper duplicate target.  They are asking completely different questions that happen to be slightly related.

Comment: No, both questions are asking how to include NBT for an item within a broader NBT tag. This user clearly knows how to give the player an item with a custom name (they even specirfy it in the question), and is asking how to test for an item with known NBT. If that isn't good enough, this is unambiguously a duplicate of [How to test for specific potions in inventories](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/270561/185203), which was closed as a duplicate of my suggested target in December.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to nest additional data tags in `tag` compound:

```
/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:bow",tag:{display:{Name:"Bow I"},ench:[{id:48,lvl:1}]}}]}
```

Learn more about item format [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_format#Item_structure).

Comment: ahh ty, that worked ^^