# How to test for specific potions in inventories?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was helping my sister with her server commands when I got stumped on this. I want to find if the player has a specific potion with this:

```
/testfor @a[team=Sandwings] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:splash_potion"}]}
```

and this:

```
{Potion:"minecraft:poison"}
```

But I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command for spawning chest with a CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/command-for-spawning-chest-with-a-canplaceon-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All item data that is not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, or `Slot` tags must be placed within a single `tag` compound:

```
/testfor @a[team=Sandwings] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:splash_potion",tag:{Potion:"minecraft:poison"}}]}
```